# Should I be using something else instead of setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
      <div class="p1">
          <a href="#" class="quickFlipCta"><img src="Test Pictures/QuestionMark.gif" /></a>
      </div>

      <div class="p2">
          <a href="#" class="quickFlipCta"><img src="Test Pictures/flower.gif" /></a>
      </div>
</div>
```

I am using a plugin that works as a flipping animation between panels (`p1` and `p2`)

The following works perfectly:

```
last.parent().parent().quickFlipper({refresh :1});
$(this).parent().parent().quickFlipper({refresh :1});
```

However, I want `$(this).parent().parent().quickFlipper({refresh :1});` to be delayed.
I tried using setTimeout:

```
last.parent().parent().quickFlipper({
    refresh: 1
});
setTimeout(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().quickFlipper({
        refresh: 1
    });
}, 1200);
```

When I do this, the function within the setTimeout is not executed at all. I was wondering if I should be using something else besides setTimeout to delay `$(this).parent().parent().quickFlipper({refresh :1});`

I have read the documentation on the plugin and nothing is there about this issue.

Here is my full code:
http://jsfiddle.net/kBDFD/

Comment: its because `this` refers to `window` in the `setTimeout`

Comment: please don't use jsfiddle to save your code, but build a working minimalistic example.

Comment: Can you link to that plugin, please? At leat to its source code?

Comment: @Amaan I doubt he did the same, for the setTimeout he is having the issue with.

Comment: The problem was that I needed to define `this` again.
I used `var that = this;`
`$(that).parent().parent().quickFlipper({refresh :1}); 
}, 1500);` and it worked. Thank you everyone for your help and input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of `setTimeout()`, you will have lost the value of `this` so that's why your code would not work (`this` will be set to the `window` object).

You can use something like this instead:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function () {
    $(self).parent().parent().quickFlipper({refresh: 1});
}, 1200);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to run second animation when first is finished or do you want to run them simultaneously but with some delay?

You can always use animation deferred object and do like this.

```
var self = this;
last.parent().parent().quickFlipper({refresh :1}).promise().done(function() {
  $(self).parent().parent().quickFlipper({refresh :1});     
});
```

Second animation will be started when first is finished.

Answer (score 1):

you cant use this in a callback, it will point to an other object

```
last.parent().parent().quickFlipper({
    refresh: 1
});
var thiz = this;
setTimeout(function () {
    $(thiz).parent().parent().quickFlipper({
        refresh: 1
    });
}, 1200);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to use a timeout. Every good plugin offers a callback when the animations are done, and even those which don't will use `.animate()`. That means, you can hook on the animation queue, either by getting the [`.promise`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) for it (like in Grzegorz' answer), or using [`.queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/):

```
last.parent().parent().quickFlipper({refresh :1}).queue(function(next) {
   $(this).parent().parent().quickFlipper({refresh :1});
   next();
});
```